# How to organize a set of scientific experiments using Git

Tags: git, scientific-computing

I'm running experiments on a model, with a workflow like this:

- I work in a model (a software in Python)
- I change some parameters and run an experiment
- Then, I will store the results of the experiment (as a pickle).
- Then, I will analyze the (pickled) results using another software (IPython Notebooks).

I'm using [Git and Scientific Reproducibility](http://computersandbuildings.com/git-and-scientific-reproducibility/) as a guide , where the results of an experiment are stored in a table along the hash of the commit. I would like to store the results in a directory instead, naming the directories as hashes.

Thinking about version control, I would like to isolate the `code` and `analysis`. For example, a change of the color in a plot in a IPython notebook in `analysis` shouldn't change anything in `code`

The approach I'm thinking:

A directory structure like this:

```
model
- code
- simulation_results
   - a83bc4
   - 23e900
   - etc 
- analysis
```

and different Git repositories for `code` and `analysis`, leaving `simulation_results` out of Git.

Any comments? A better solution? Thanks.

Comment: What hex numbers under simulation_results should mean? (I guess they are commit IDs, but I miss some context.)

Comment: I maintain submodules are a good approach.I have edited and detailed my answer.

Comment: Hi Josef, Yes indeed the hex numbers are commit ids.

Comment: Hi VonC. Thank you for detailing your answer, its very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems sound, and your structure would be a good fit for using **[`git submodules`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, `model` becoming a parent git repo.

That way, you will link together `code`, and `analysis` SHA1 within the `model` repo.

That means you can create your directory within the private (ie not versioned) directory `model/simulation_results` based on the SHA1 of `model` repo (the "parent" repo): that SHA1 links the SHA1 of both `project` and `analysis` submodules, which means you can reproduce the experiment *exactly* (based on the exact content of both `project` and `analysis`).